# Symfony phpCurl Authorization header

Tags: symfony, curl, authorization

I do curl from one controller to another.

```
$ch = curl_init($url . '?' . http_build_query($get));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';

if ($session->get('access_token'))
    $headers[] = 'Authorization:' . $session->get('access_token');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I dump `$request->headers->all()` in that destination controller and always get only the accept header. If I comment the accept header, it will still be there but only empty. It never gets authorization.

This code does not seem to be missing anything, so what may be wrong?

Comment: Well, is `$session->get('access_token')` null by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking if `$session->get('access_token')` is not null (*since you check for it in your code, this might be the culprit*), I think your **Authorization** header should rather be :

```
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Basic ' . $session->get('access_token');
```

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)